# When will there be a 'proper' moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Okay, it looks like moving out of beta will happen soon (based on [this thread](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup), for example). So I wonder what happens about the moderator situation: do we have an election for moderators at some stage? After all, the current team were appointed *pro tem*, and I guess that there may be others who wish to put their hats into the ring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [“Is there a time when we elect non-temporary moderators on an SE 2.0 site ?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/is-there-a-time-when-we-elect-non-temporary-moderators-on-an-se-2-0-site/69361#69361):

> The nominations for moderator elections will start about 30 days after a site graduates from beta.

Comment: That seems to cover it pretty well: I was not sure if the election had to happen before the end of the beta.

Comment: I would add that the first sites are well past their 30 day mark. The nomination software is well underway but will not likely be deployed for another week or two. But moderator nominations are coming.

Comment: @Robert: I think we're past the 30 day mark now.