# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all,

Thank you for your helpful [design input](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup). As you can see, the new design went live, grats!

If you see any CSS/Styling issues, please **start a new question** for the bug report, and tag it with "Design" and "Bug." It will be a lot easier for me to track new questions than reading the comments replied to this thread.

The favicons may be cached by your browsers, to see the new ones, load the following URL in your browser's address bar and hard refresh.

http://sstatic.net/tex/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/texmeta/img/favicon.ico

Regarding the header background montage, I have used some of your suggestions. I'm still keeping it very subtle, since it's used for pure decorative purpose only. The content of the background image isn't final, I'm always up for suggestions.

Designing this site has been an educational experience for me. I've learned quite a bit about what TeX can do! Thank you for such a wonderful community and congratulations on the launch.

BTW: I'll be hanging around the [TeX chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41)  you can catch me there for design discussions.

Comment: Wow: I reloaded the page to check for any new answers, and there was the new design! Surprised and impressed by the speed :-)

Comment: Thank you!  The Indian quarter of the montage looks particularly good.

Comment: Very nice! Jin has done an excellent job as with the design, as usual. My fingers itch to start playing and poking it around, but so far it looks stunning.

Comment: @charles: This is not Indian. I wonder how many people realize what it [says there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring#Inscription) when they come to this site today. Maybe we someone with knowledge of the black language can change “ring” to ”typesetting system” :)

Comment: @caramdir: +1000!  Funnily enough, I've just included that self-same inscription in a TikZ picture ...

Comment: (As a rabid Tolkien fan, I thoroughly approve of the inclusion)

Comment: Very beautiful design! And featuring Tengwar to boot! :)

Comment: @Caramdir: Decisively outgeeked!  I had guessed it was Devanagari...

Comment: This is great! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Caramdir: TeX may bind us all, but it binds us in the light, not the darkness, and with golden shackles...

Comment: I love it! Simple and butiful like TeX.

Answer (score 9):

Wow, I like it. Looks great.

Answer (score 3):

Lovely!

However, there is one thing that felt strange right away, the tags. Is it just me or are they much harder to spot/read now? They seem to blend in too much with the text.

On a more general and offtopic note (sorry I couldn't avoid it), I am totally hyped about the official launch of the TeX stackexchange, and in fact the whole stackexchange suite in general. The time when I worked without using these sites seems to be years away.

Comment: Maybe you see the braces and are primed for Tex, not tags?

Comment: @JCL I've started using bracket treatment for some of the recently launched SE sites, such as Math and Photography. I feel brackets make the body area cleaner, v.s. a solid color block. Of course this is a lot different from the Beta theme, so I think it's a matter of getting used to it(won't take long!). And thanks, it's been challenging and fun designing all these SE sites.

Comment: I like the braces. But I kind of see @JCL's point. Perhaps, instead of a solid color background to the tags, the entire tag *area* could be delineated somehow, so it's clearer that it's not part of the question text? I'm fine with it as it is now, tbh, just suggesting something that may or may not work. :)

Comment: @JCL I'm begining to see @JCL's point too. Even though {} is a fitting visual treatment, it can be confusing. I'll try to put a subtle background color to the tags, but very faint.

Comment: @Jin: Did you add it yet? Because if you did, it's still too faint (at least here on meta).

Comment: @SamB, not yet. but it's on my todo list. it will be in soon.

Answer (score 3):

I do think this design is beautiful, elegant and subtle.

Comment: I am left wondering if it isn't a little bit *too* beautiful...

Answer (score 0):

Very, very nice. What about a new favicon though?

Comment: see my post about how to hard refresh new favicons. Keep in mind though, sometimes even hard freshing doesn't work in Chrome(at least for me).

Comment: Yes, for some reason they didn't work for me either on Chrome. But they look fab when I opened the page in Safari.

Comment: wow. not sure how I missed that. thanks!

Comment: @Jin: It *is* a bit of a pain that favicons are (more or less) tied to a fixed path, isn't it? Otherwise, if one wanted to deploy a new favicon, one could simply do so under a new filename, which would quite effectively communicate the need to fetch it to even the most obstinate of browsers (e.g. Links).

Comment: @Jin: Also, it is a quite nice favicon. Minimalist, and quite mnemonic. (As opposed to math.SE's favicon, for example. Admittedly, that one has a harder job to do, what with the typical user having to keep mathoverflow and math.SE straight and all.)

Answer (score 0):

Really beautiful. Congratulations to everyone who contributed.

My only, very small, "but" is that it doesn't include a Feynman diagram...

Answer (score 0):

Very nice job, as well as for the other sites. And I just noticed that you used one of my drawings ;-)