# Chemical equation in background is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

This issue is extremely minor, but the equation on the TeX Meta page is incorrect. Na + Cl yields NaCl and not Na + Cl

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? Please leave a reason too should you decide to downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You should really, really take a deeper look on the equation! Is it perhaps caused by a bad monitor resolution?*

The same background is used on the main site TeX.SE. For the background of this background you should read [Site Design Ideas (updated with mockup)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup) <sup><sub>(and later [New Design Launched](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/new-design-launched) )</sub></sup>.

For the equation see especially this answer: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/649/, though it is not exactly the same – the equation used for the background is actually in the correct form (it’s taken from the [TeXample source](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oxidation-and-reduction/)).

Comment: I didn't notice it said oxidation and reduction, my mistake!