# When was the TeX - LaTeX site at Stack Exchange founded?

Tags: support, stackexchange

When was TeX.SE founded? I notice that a lot of early questions were migrated from StackOverflow. So I'm wondering when the actual TeX.SE site was created.

Comment: Approximate answer: 2 years and 6 months ago, which would be July 14, 2010 (https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest)

Comment: More dates in the right column here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148

Comment: @doncherry The link you meant is https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest.

Comment: I've been on the site since private beta day one: 26th July 2010.

Comment: Since SE just numbers posts sequentially by when they first appeared on the site, it's easy to find the first question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1/ — 2010-07-26 19:14:18Z

Comment: @Caramdir Thanks. / By the way, what I did was to look at "Questions" in their (default) sorted-by-"newest" view, went to the last page, and started going through those questions. It turned out lots of them were marked as "migrated from stackoverflow.com", so I didn't want to go through all of them manually to find the first non-migrated question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The exact day of the proposal on area51 is Jun 2 '10 at 14:20. It can be seen in the [revision history](http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/2148/revisions) of the proposal post.

As doncherry said in his comment above, dates are at the right side on the [TeX.SE proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148). It currently shows "commitment start 2 years ago" etc. However, looking at the source code of the web page you can see the exact dates, so here's the time line:

- **proposed:** 2010-06-02 14:20:32Z
- **commitment start:** 2010-06-22 02:35:48Z
- **private beta start:** 2010-07-26 19:00:00Z
- **public beta start:** 2010-08-02 19:00:00Z
- **[launched with new design:](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/new-design-launched)** 2010-11-11

Comment: For most of the dates on [a51], the precise date is also displayed as a mouseover-tooltip.

Comment: @doncherry Thanks to all for these answers! I just browsed the SE site casually, and didn't want to click myself through every link and try out every mouseover to figure this out, but it's great to have all the dates in one place now. I suppose it's always more obvious to experienced users (for just about everything).

Comment: @doncherry Thanks, my mouse moved to fast for letting the tooltips show up. :-)

Comment: Damn, graduation after 5 months and 9 days, that is quite fast :)

Comment: Also see [Timeline of Stack Exchange sites](https://web.archive.org/web/20160524035741/https://normalhuman.github.io/timeline/).