# Why are there tengwar on the TeX stack exchange background?

Tags: discussion

The top left of the [background image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/texmeta/img/bg-graph-top.png?v=869b540f883a) contains the tengwar (elvish script) for *"ash nazg durbatulük, ash nazg gimbatul,"* ("One ring to rule them all; one ring to find them") the first line of the inscription on the One Ring in Tolkien's *Lord of the Rings*.

Why?  And how is this relevant to TeX, besides the fact that it looks cool, and TeX produces good-looking text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think the reasoning is just that: _it looks cool, and TeX produces good-looking text!_ ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler -- but also that *tex can produce good-looking text in any language for which you have a suitable font".

Comment: you might be interested in looking at some of the discussion that went into creating the "look" of the site: [Site Design Ideas (updated with mockup)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/638/579) and [New Design Launched](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/650/579)

Comment: I suppose this question could potentially be marked/closed as a duplicate, although for some reason my initial searches got me no results--I had been searching by the transliteration.  Unsurprisingly, searching "ash nazg" doesn't get very many responses (well, 1 now!)

Comment: It's related to TeX in the sense that you can use different (non-standard) fonts under XeLaTeX (or similar engines). See [What package allows Elvish in TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13015/5764)

Comment: A tengwar font is one of the oldest MetaFont fonts on CTAN. :-)

Comment: For other items on the background http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/tex-sx-background-to-be-used-in-a-document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was [part of the site design process](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/638/5764), which [went live around November 2010](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/650/5764).

Specifically, the Tengwar text in the design was [suggested](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/649/5764) as part of a font-related [TeX Showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/tengwar.pdf).

The following post also has related TeX content:

- [What package allows Elvish in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13015/5764)

Comment: I think @Werner got it right in his post, but I'd like to think of the SE community as a ring of people on a quest for answers....