# What does the text around the title say?

Tags: discussion

This is a silly question, but if I don't ask it, it will bug me. I can recognise most of the text around the TEX title, except the elvish in the top right hand corner. What does it say?

Comment: Related question on the main site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13015/86

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The translation of the (complete) Elvish text is:

> One ring to rule them all, one ring to find them, One ring to bring
>   them all and in the darkness bind them.

It's the inscription of the [One Ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring), in the site design we can see the first half of it.

Comment: I always thought it meant: `! Error: You shall not pass!`

Comment: @MartinScharrer I also thought it meant : `Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:...`. To be honest, the log file is elvish to me anyway.

Comment: Was the title design made in TeX?

Comment: @Village: I would assume so: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/649/4012

Comment: Technically that is written in the Black Speech of Mordor as I recall, but it uses the same writting as Elvish.

Comment: Dammit, that was pointed out below already.

Answer (score 20):

The Elvish text at the top left of the site design

[image: Elvish at tex.stackexchange]

is the first half of the inscription on the [One Ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring):

[image: J. R. R. Tolkien: Lord of the Rings]

See [Site Design Ideas](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/649/4012), the [TeX showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/), source [tengwar.tex](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/tengwar.tex) and compilation result [tengwar.pdf](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/tengwar.pdf). About how to create it with TeX see [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex).

The language is "Black Speech", the letters are "Tengwar" (Elvish). This is similar to writing "Γρεεκ λεττερς" with Greek letters but using English language (in Latin letters: "Greek letters").

> "Black Speech was the language created by Sauron for his servants in
>   Mordor. Over the centuries many of the Orcs developed their own
>   dialects of Black Speech, these dialects were often referred to as
>   Orkish. The Orcs were not a very literate group, so few examples of
>   their writing exists today. Those few Orks that could write used the
>   Cirth alphabet. Tolkien included one example of written Black Speech
>   in the book "The Lord of the Rings" - the Ring inscription. This
>   inscription seems to be unique in that it uses the Tengwar alphabet.
>   Sauron apparently adapted the Tengwar script of Eregion for writing
>   for Black Speech. […] Writing Black Speech with Tengwar: The rules for
>   writing Black Speech with Tengwar is similar to the Sindarin
>   Tengwar/Tehtar Mode. Although the Black Speech and the Sindarin
>   Tengwar/Tehtar modes look similar to each other, they may use
>   different Tengwar letters to represent the same sounds. This is
>   particularly noticeable with the phonetic values assigned to the
>   Tehtar marks used for the o and u sound, which are reversed."

(Daniel Steven Smith: TengwarQuenya_Help, 10/FEB/2003, http://chomikuj.pl/anuleczek88/r*c3*b3*c5*bcne/fonty+-+elficki/TengwarQuenya_Help,354460461.pdf)

As for the rhyme of "bind" and "find" also in Black Speech as noted by Mark S. Everitt: Some say that Orcs were created by corrupting Elves (e.g. [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc_(Middle-earth)#East_Elves_.28Avari.29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc_%28Middle-earth%29#East_Elves_.28Avari.29) ), which the Elves deny, of course. Now one just needs to find out whether English is derived from Elvish or Orcish. ;-)

You could also be interested in the coming [The Hobbit movies](http://www.thehobbitblog.com/) and [rpg.stackexchange.com](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Things to note:

- You need to look very hard to see the *writing*.
- When you save the page, that part isn’t saved and therefore *invisible*
  in the saved version.
- The site is *bright* (a lot of white) and *cool* at the same time.
- Orcs use "nazg" not only for "ring" but also for "website". Wait,
  that’s an urban myth, isn’t it? ;-)

Comment: I find it amazing that "bind" and "find" rhyme in elvish too...