# Tengwar in the background

Tags: discussion, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the text around the title say?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/what-does-the-text-around-the-title-say)

The background in the header contains the Ring inscription (top left)... Is it by any chance taken from the [tengwarscript](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/tengwarscript.html) package?

Comment: See [What does the text around the title say?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2106) which also links to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/649/2975

Comment: @Martin Ah... so it comes from the TeX Showcase and ultimately from tengwarscript... nice to see a (tiny) contribution of mine in the site :)