# TeX.SX background to be used in a document

Tags: discussion, fun

Is the background here at TeX.SX copyrighted? If not, does any one know about a MWE which replicates the background on the webpage? I have always been amazed at it and would like to use it as a background of a document. I did some search on the webpage and I was able to extract the `.png` file below:

[image]

I would like to use it as a background for `letterpaper` size documents. One of the diagrams seems familiar; the one with the triangle. If am not mistaken it is similar to the one from [TeXample.net](http://texample.net).

Comment: AFAIK, all content of the site is creative commons. The triangle is from http://texample.net/tikz/examples/rotated-triangle/ and the Elvish from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex.  Can you increase the contrast and re-upload?

Comment: The sphere on the right is by Herbert Voß via PSTricks.

Comment: Isn't [**cc-wiki**](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) allows the usage with a proper credit?

Comment: @percusse: It's available from the [PSTricks 3D gallery](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D) as [`exa007.tex`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Gallery3D/exa007.tex).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The chemical reaction : [Oxidation/reduction arrows, overhead and below, with oxidation numbers also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18145/oxidation-reduction-arrows-overhead-and-below-with-oxidation-numbers-also)

Elvish text : [What package allows Elvish in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex)

The middle part : I think these are the images used

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pancake-network/

http://texample.net/tikz/examples/rotated-triangle/

as one of them is mentioned already. Read more from the graphics design story here

[Site Design Ideas (updated with mockup)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup)

The rest looks like straightforward to replicate via math-mode, or I made it invisible during a simple contrast modification...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

<sub>[Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251996/5764)</sub>

The (original) image was created using [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html#Source) (available from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epix)). The source [`sphere.xp`](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/sphere.xp) can be compiled using

```
elaps <options> sphere.xp
```

to [produce](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/sphere.pdf)

[image]

#### [`sphere.xp`](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/sphere.xp):

```
/* -*-ePiX-*- */
#include "epix.h"
using namespace ePiX;

const double k(2*M_PI/(360*sqrt(3))); // assume "degrees" mode

double exp_cos(double t) { return exp(k*t)*Cos(t); }
double exp_sin(double t) { return exp(k*t)*Sin(t); }
double minus_exp_cos(double t) { return -exp_cos(t); }
double minus_exp_sin(double t) { return -exp_sin(t); }

int main()
{
  picture(P(-1,-1), P(1,1), "2.5 x 2.5in");

  begin();
  degrees(); // set angle units
  camera.at(P(1, 2.5, 3));

  sphere(); // draw unit sphere's horizon

  pen(Blue(1.6)); // hidden portions of loxodromes
  backplot_N(exp_cos, exp_sin, -540, 540, 180);
  backplot_N(minus_exp_cos, minus_exp_sin, -540, 540, 180);

  pen(Red(1.6));
  backplot_N(exp_sin, minus_exp_cos, -540, 540, 180);
  backplot_N(minus_exp_sin, exp_cos, -540, 540, 180);

  pen(Black(0.3)); // coordinate grid

  for (int i=0; i<=12; ++i) {
    latitude(90-15*i, 0, 360);
    longitude(30*i, 0, 360);
  }

  bold(Blue()); // visible portions of loxodromes
  frontplot_N(exp_cos, exp_sin, -540, 540, 360);
  frontplot_N(minus_exp_cos, minus_exp_sin, -540, 540, 360);

  pen(Red());
  frontplot_N(exp_sin, minus_exp_cos, -540, 540, 360);
  frontplot_N(minus_exp_sin, exp_cos, -540, 540, 360);

  end();
}
```

Possible outputs:

- [LaTeX's `picture` environment](http://pastebin.com/CAL6q0VJ); `elaps sphere.xp`
- [PSTricks](http://pastebin.com/8C4SgejN); `elaps --pst sphere.xp`
- [TikZ](http://pastebin.com/yVxYCerp); `elaps --tikz sphere.xp`